# Gap between offset walls in print in Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I've been printing a lot of things with 1 mm offset walls to fit lids.

[image: Screenshot of an unsliced model in Cura]

However, in Cura, it's been slicing them but not compensating for the offset creating gaps since the shell thickness (0.8 mm) is less than the offset. This results in gaps and occasionally allows corners to warp.

[image: Screenshot of a sliced model in Cura]

IMO it should be creating a layer that sits below the inset wall, filling the gap (i.e. making a thicker wall on the last layer before the inset wall). I've looked through the settings in Cura and couldn't find anything to do this.

I could increase the wall thickness but this will result in unnecessary extra printing time/filament.

[image: Screenshot showing a layer example in Cura]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "Skin Removal Width" options in Cura. You might need to unhide them if they're not shown by default. As I understand it, the *intent* is that the "Skin Expand Distance" feature right next to it is supposed to re-expand the skin areas after shrinking them in a way that results in fewer tiny awkward-shaped regions that are slow to fill; however, as you've found, regions narrower than the wall line width can be lost completely. Setting the "Skin Removal Width" to 0 (and optionally doing the same for "Skin Expand Distance" since it should no longer be needed) will likely fix this.

Comment: Thanks! I set it to 0.6mm instead of the default 0.8mm and it worked and should still do the intended function you described (I assume).

Comment: @Tyndal: Great! I wonder if this is a numerical stability bug from something that, in mathematical exactness, should be at or just over 2 wall line widths, coming out slightly under and getting deleted. Does 0.79 or so also work? Knowing that could be helpful to reporting the bug and getting it fixed.

Comment: Setting it to 0.79 also worked. Anything 0.8 or over fails. I also tried it with a wall thickness of 1.2 and oddly 0.79 didn't work anymore, I had to set it to 0.78.